# Firefox : 2 different URLs for bookmarks : keyword (for as search engine) and base

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, search-engines, keyword

With a bookmark of IMDb `http://www.imdb.com/find?q=%s` and a keyword `imdb`, I can type `imdb seven` then enter, and it will send me at `http://www.imdb.com/find?q=seven`.

With the same bookmark or another one how can I make `imdb` then enter go to `http://www.imdb.com/`, and not `http://www.imdb.com/find?q=`?

**EDIT**

Thanks to **iglvzx**, here's a JavaScript solution (original script by iglvzx, modified to load the main URL if the bookmark is selected in Firefox's menus). `m` is main URL, `s` is search. See his answer for more information.

```
javascript:(function(){var q='%s',m='http://www.google.com/',s='http://www.google.com/search?q='+q;if(keywords==''||keywords=='%'+'s'){window.location=m;}else{window.location=s;}})();
```

Comment: Couldn't you save the second bookmark as `imd`? Then just type imd, instead of imdb. It's even shorter ;)

Comment: I haven't imdb only… But yes, it'll be the solution if there's no aleternative! ;)

Comment: Than maybe make an unified syntax, say prepend `s` as in search to the site name. So `simdb`, `swiki`, `sgoogle` etc...

Comment: Yes, good idea. But I can't figure out I'm the first one trying to do this! (Or there's no way in 12 version of Ff !)

Comment: @Didjo Good catch on the `%s` case! I will include that in my answer, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with a JavaScript [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). I will post the uncompressed code first (so it's easy to read), and then the code compressed to a single line for Firefox.

---

**Uncompressed:** <sup>Thanks, [@Didjo](https://superuser.com/revisions/422080/2), for catching the extra `%s` case!</sup>

```
javascript:
(function(){

    var keywords = "%s";
    var mainURL = "https://superuser.com/";
    var searchURL = "https://superuser.com/search?q=" + keywords;

    if (keywords == "" || keywords == "%" + "s")
    {
        window.location = mainURL;
    }
    else
    {
        window.location = searchURL;
    }

})();
```

---

**Compressed:**

```
javascript:(function(){var keywords="%s";var mainURL="https://superuser.com/";var searchURL="https://superuser.com/search?q="+keywords;if(keywords==""||keywords=="%"+"s"){window.location=mainURL}else{window.location=searchURL}})();
```

---

**Setup**:

1. Create a new bookmark. Open the **Firefox Library**.

   [image: library]
2. Select a folder. **Right-click** and select `New Bookmark...`.

   [image: new bookmark]
3. Enter the name, location, and keyword fields for the bookmark, **pasting** the JavaScript bookmarklet as the location.

   [image: add]
4. Close the Library.

---

**Demo:**

Now, you can launch a location or perform a search using a single keyword!

- With **no** search keywords:

  [image: no keywords]

  [image: mainURL]
- With search keywords:

  [image: search keywords]

  [image: searchURL]

### Video Demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGNU5FiogXM

Comment: THAT is a very good idea. Thanks. But it's still a very huge lack in Firefox… (And Chrome, BTW.) Thanks again, this idea rocks. (I didn't tried it yet but just thaught: Firefox disabled javascript from address bar, didn't it?)

Comment: I used Firefox 12 with default settings in my example. Yes, you have to call the JavaScript from a bookmark. You can't paste it directly into the address bar.

Comment: This method delete bookmark favicon. I tried the Bookmark Favicon Changer plug-in but it doesn't work. Got a JS idea? ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Add to Search Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-to-search-bar/) does exactly what you want. For example, when you type `imdb battleship` it searchs for the movie `battleship`, but when you type `imdb`, it opens imdb.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiple bookmarks with different name (say prepending a letter) as discussed in the comments.

Other than that, you may want to try the [instafox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/instantfox/?src=search). Combined with bookmarks, it could give you the desired result.

Comment: This plugin looks great! I'm gonna look around it. Thank you! (I let open in case someone has a plugin-free solution!)